# Locate an Element Which Will Come in Four Different Scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<input type="submit" name="ccBtnBook" value="Book" id="ccBtnBook" 
class="bookbtn2 flR" style="background-color:Transparent;border- 
style:None;">

<input type="submit" name="ccRepItinerary$ctl00$ccLbtnSelect" value="Book" 
id="ccRepItinerary_ctl00_ccLbtnSelect" class="bookbtn2" style="background- 
color:Transparent;border-style:None;">

<input type="button" value=" Book " class="bookbtn2" onclick="iSB('1')">

<input type="button" value=" Book " class="bookbtn2" 
onclick="iSB('4','MCT','DXB','DXB','MCT','True')">

<input type="button" value=" Book " class="bookbtn2" 
onclick="iSB('1','MCT','DXB','','','False')">

<input type="button" value=" Book " class="bookbtn2" onclick="iSB('4')">
```

I have tried using the class name and xpath, but failed for both.
I even tried to use a JavaScript click.

For case two finding the element by its ID works.

Comment: You mean the element could be any one of those options? you should also post what you tried and what was the problem with it?

Comment: I have edited the context

Comment: You didn't add any new information. *I have tried using* doesn't mean anything. Post the code and tell what happened when you tried it. If there is an error message post it as well.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.className("bookbtn2")).click();

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.bookbtn2")));

Comment: Error is, Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

Use the class, that seems to be common

```
//*[contains(@class, 'bookbtn2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the element in four different scenarios you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.bookbtn2[value='Book'][type='button'][onclick^='iSB']"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='bookbtn2' and @value='Book'][@type='button' and starts-with(@onclick,'iSB')]"));
  ```